# How to do a projection of one vector over two others?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How to calculate the projection of the last vector (let's call it $D$) on the first two (let's call them $A$ and $B$)?

\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -5\\
\end{bmatrix}

I would be very thankful if you can give me a method to do it.

The only thing I have is

$$p(x) = \sum \limits _{k=1} ^n \frac {| \langle x | e_k \rangle |^2} { \langle e_k | e_k \rangle }$$

which I don't understand.

Comment: Does your linear algebra class actually use bra-ket notation?  Interesting.  But your projection formula is off.  That would produce a scalar where a projection should be a vector.  The formula should look more like $$\operatorname{proj}_{W}\lvert x\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert e_k\rangle\langle e_k\rvert x\rangle$$ where $W = \operatorname{span}\left(\lvert e_1\rangle, \dots, \lvert e_n\rangle\right)$.

Comment: Are you supposed to compute the two individual projections onto the vectors or the projection onto the space spanned by the first two vectors?